# A lebesgue integral property.

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $(E, B, \mu)$ be a measurable space¸ such that $\mu(E) = 1$. Let $f, g : E → R$ measurable functions such that $fg > 1$. Show that $||f||_{L^1}||g||_{L^1} > 1$.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is equivalent to saying that $||f||_{L^1}>\frac{1}{||g||_{L1}}$. Note that $||g||_{L^1}\leq ||g||_{\infty}\mu(A)=||g||_{\infty}$ and that g is nonzero almost everwhere, as $fg(a)>1$ for almost all $a\in A$. So $g^{-1}$ is measurable and $||g\cdot g^{-1}||_{L^1}\leq ||g^{-1}||_{\infty}||g||_{L^1}$. From this it follows that
$$||f||_{L^1}=\int_A|f|d\mu>\int_A\frac{1}{|g|}d\mu\geq ||g^{-1}||_{\infty}\geq \frac{1}{||g||_{L^1}}.$$
Which is what we wanted.

Comment: is there another way to respond without using the infinity norm?

Comment: What is the problem with the infinity norm?

Comment: I don't understand the inequalities
 ||g||L1≤||g||∞μ(A) and  ||g⋅g−1||L1≤||g−1||∞||g||L1

Comment: These are Hölder inequalities. They can be easily obtained by the definition of the integral.

Comment: I think the Holder inequality must satisfy (1 / p + 1 / q) = 1, where f \in Lp and g \in Lq. In this case, this is not satisfied, as p=q=1.

Comment: This is for $p=\infty$.

Comment: ||1/g||_L1 ≥ ||g^{−1}||∞?